# Python While loop Until 0

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have this code down so far but it is asking me to use a while loop to repeatedly ask the user for a denominator for as long as the denominator is 0. Edit: I believe the code I'm missing goes in between the denominator= and if numerator = int(input...

```
numerator = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))
denominator = int(input("Enter denominator: "))


if numerator / denominator * denominator == numerator:
    print "Divides evenly!"
else:
    print "Doesn't divide evenly."
```

Comment: "It is asking you"?  What "it"?

Comment: Sorry, it is a school program that I am having difficulty with. I'll post the assignment detail if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code out using `try` and `except` to catch the error of division by 0

CODE:

```
while True:
    numerator = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))

    denominator = int(input("Enter denominator: "))

    try:
        if numerator / denominator * denominator == numerator:
            print "Divides evenly!"
        else:
            print "Doesn't divide evenly."
    except:
        print "Sorry demoninator cannot be zero"
```

But does this work in python 2.x ? im not sure. Give it a try

Answer (score 2):

use a while loop: and read [break instruction](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

```
numerator = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))
while True:
   denominator = int(input("Enter denominator: "))
   if denominator != 0:
       break

if numerator / denominator * denominator == numerator:
    print "Divides evenly!"
else:
    print "Doesn't divide evenly."
```